# Cannot run any command after `org-occur'

Tags: org-mode

I am running `org-occur` in my elisp code to focus on entries marked "TODO ", and then I try to go to the beginning of the buffer like so:

```lisp
(local-set-key (kbd "s-5")  ;; `s' = super key
               (lambda () 
                 "org-occur TODOS"
                 (interactive)
                 (let ((p0 (point-min)))
                   (org-occur "TODO ") ;; <--- NOTHNING AFTER THIS LINE WORKS
                   (goto-char p0)  ;; <-- does not work
                   (search-backward "#+title") ;; <-- this neither
                   )))
```

But the lines following `(org-occur "TODO ")` are not executed. Is `org-occur` running something like `save-excursion` to prevent changing the view?

### Edit

Okay, looking at the `org-occur` source code, it runs a hook when it's almost finished executing:

`(run-hooks 'org-occur-hook)`

Looking up the variable `org-occur-hook`, I see this:

```
org-occur-hook is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is (org-first-headline-recenter)

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Hook that is run after ‘org-occur’ has constructed a sparse tree.
This can be used to recenter the window to show as much of the structure
as possible.

You can customize this variable.
```

Checking the relevant part in `org.el` I see this:

```lisp
(defcustom org-occur-hook '(org-first-headline-recenter)
  "Hook that is run after `org-occur' has constructed a sparse tree.
This can be used to recenter the window to show as much of the structure
as possible."
  :group 'org-sparse-trees
  :type 'hook)
```

So this function is run after `org-occur` is completed:

`(org-first-headline-recenter)`

In my case, I'd have to set that hook to `nil` and then set it back to the previous value to be able to change the view.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and then re-adding the hook solved it for me. This here works:

```lisp
(local-set-key (kbd "s-5") (lambda ()
                             "org-occur TODOS"
                             (interactive)                                         
                             (let ((p0 (point-min)))
                               (remove-hook 'org-occur-hook 'org-first-headline-recenter)
                               (org-occur "TODO ")
                               (goto-char p0)
                               (search-backward "#+title")
                               (add-hook 'org-occur-hook 'org-first-headline-recenter)                                                                                      
                               )
                             ))
```